# Scheme set made from parts of set

Tags: set, scheme

Hi i'm trying to define a function which should make a set from the parts of that set.
Should be defined like:  P(A) = P(A-{x}) U { {x} U B} for all B that belongs to P(A-{X}) where X belongs to A.

A test would be:

> (parts '(a b c))
>     => ((a b c) (a b) (a c) (a) (b c) (b) (c)())

I've been trying with this one:

(define (mapc f x l)
  (if (null? l)
      l
      (cons (f x (car l)) (mapc f x (cdr l)))))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?  (untested)

```
(define (power-set A)
   (cond 
     [(null? A) '()]  ; the power set of an empty set it empty
     [else      (append (map (lambda (S) (cons x S)) ; sets with x
                             (power-set (cdr A)))
                        (power-set (cdr A))          ; sets without x
                        ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially 'combinations' function (https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=combinations#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._combinations%29%29).

Following short code in Racket (a Scheme derivative) gets all combinations or parts:

```
(define (myCombinations L)
  (define ol (list L))       ; Define outlist and add full list as one combination; 
  (let loop ((L L))          ; Recursive loop where elements are removed one by one..
    (for ((i L))             ; ..to create progressively smaller combinations;
      (define K (remove i L))
      (set! ol (cons K ol))  ; Add new combination to outlist;
      (loop K)))
  (remove-duplicates ol))
```

Testing:

```
(myCombinations '(a b c))
```

Output:

```
'(() (a) (b) (a b) (c) (a c) (b c) (a b c))
```